# parallel, foreach, exported object not found

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have the following (sample) code which is executed in passive mode on computing clusters:

```
> foo <- function(...)
> {
> require(copula)
> require(foreach)
> require(methods)
> require(np)
> require(parallel)
> {cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1) ; registerDoParallel(cl)}
...
> str(dat)
'data.frame':   31269 obs. of  15 variables
...
> clusterExport(cl=cl,varlist=c("dat",...))
> dumpster <- foreach(i=1:10,.packages=c("copula","foreach","np"),.export=c("dat"))%dopar%
> {... ; dat.new <- some.fn(dat) ; ...}
...
> stopCluster(cl)
> }
> foo(...)
Error in get(name, envir = envir) : object 'dat' not found
Calls: foo ... postNode -> sendData -> sendData.SOCKnode -> serialize -> get
Execution halted
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mixed up some instruction, to make order do this

```
library(doSNOW)
library(foreach)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1, type = "SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)
```

I'm assuming that the object `dat` was already availaible and so this is how you use the foreach

```
dumpster <- foreach(i=1:10,.packages=c("copula","np"), .combine = c)%dopar%{dat.new <- some.fn(dat)}
```

Then close the clusters

```
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But indeed there was nothing mixed up. I chose the 'parallel' package since it suited my needs. The other packages are needed for my computations and I posted them in case some incompatibilities existed without my knowledge. Finally, the reason was that 'dat' was too big to be replicated so often within the cluster, causing memory issues and hence the cluster to break.

Comment: I had the same problem myself, I hope all worked out for you.

Comment: Yeah finally... Just a pain in the ass to find out based on the "object 'dat' not found" error which - in my eyes - makes no sense in case of such an error.

Comment: Exactly, I thought that something went wrong in the environment and so R wasn't able to find the object while parallelizing the function.