# Error in checkForRemote Errors (lapply(cl, recvResult)) 3 Nodes Produced Errors; first error: object '.doSnowGlobals' not found in R for tidymodel

Tags: r, machine-learning, tidyverse, random-forest, tidymodels

I am attempting to create a Random Forest Regression model in R using parsnip tidymodels. I am following [this tutorial](https://juliasilge.com/blog/sf-trees-random-tuning/) but using regression instead of classification. I run into an issue when I run this line of code.

```
doParallel::registerDoParallel()

set.seed(345)
tune_res <- tune_grid(
  tune_wf,
  resamples = trees_folds,
  grid = 20
)
```

**The error is as follows:**

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
  3 nodes produced errors; first error: object '.doSnowGlobals' not found
```

I have looked at the following SO threada to attempt to resolve this question before asking it myself

1. [error: object '.doSnowGlobals' not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079527/error-object-dosnowglobals-not-found)
2. [parallel, foreach, exported object not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38695489/parallel-foreach-exported-object-not-found)
3. [Error in check for remote errors (val): 5 nodes produced an error: object not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47424367/error-in-check-for-remote-errors-val-5-nodes-produced-an-error-object-not-fo)

None of which resolved my issue and none of which helped me fully understand what the issue may be.

For more context here is all my script:

```
# Splitting out the Data Between Training & Testing -------
set.seed(123)

# Creating Inital Split 
tree_split <- initial_split(stc_boise, strata = DELIVERY_BUS_DAYS, prop = .80)

# Creating Training Set 
tree_train <- training(tree_split)

# Creating Test Set 
tree_test <- testing(tree_split)

# Create Recipe 
tree_rec <- recipe(DELIVERY_BUS_DAYS     ~ DOW + MVNDR_NBR + BRANCH_ID +  STR_NBR + MKT_NBR + RGN_NBR + DISNACE, data = tree_train) 
tree_prep <- prep(tree_rec)
juiced <- juice(tree_prep)

# Specifying the Specs of the Engine 
tune_spec <- rand_forest(
  mtry = tune(),
  trees = 1000,
  min_n = tune()
) %>%
  set_mode("regression") %>%
  set_engine("randomForest")

# Creating the Model Workflow
tune_wf <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(tree_rec) %>%
  add_model(tune_spec)

# Train Hyperparameters 
set.seed(234)
trees_folds <- vfold_cv(tree_train)


# Tune the Model 
doParallel::registerDoParallel()

set.seed(345)
tune_res <- tune_grid(
  tune_wf,
  resamples = trees_folds,
  grid = 20
)

tune_res
```

I have installed all required packages for parallel computing such as: `doParallel, doSNOW`, am I missing any?

If someone can provide a solution, may you share the code that I can fix it with please? And also, possibly provide an explination for the error so I fully understand why I am facing this error>

Comment: I recommend you [check out this guidance on how to set up parallel processing for tune](https://tune.tidymodels.org/articles/extras/optimizations.html#parallel-processing-1).